# Add native Android/iOS widget to dotnet Maui application

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have native iOS and Android widgets written in Swift and Kotlin respectively. Is there a way to bundle these widgets into a dotnet Maui application? I know that for iOS, that would involve adding an additional target in xcode but I don't see a way to do that with Visual Studio. Is this even possible with the way dotnet Maui works?

Comment: As of today, there is no way to create a Widget using .NET MAUI, the only way to do this is creating it in Swift and embedding it into your app via msbuild targets.  For more information, please check: [Embedded WidgetKit Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios14/#embedded-widgetkit-support).